# How do I configure nginx to handle virtual paths (paths handled by Drupal) properly?

Tags: ddev

I have a virtual `/xmlrpc.php` route on my Drupal site. It's for legacy compatibility. With the default DDEV configuration, nginx returns "No input file specified." when I visit https://mysite.ddev.local/xmlrpc.php.

How can I make it ask Drupal to handle the request instead?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes the use of DDEV 1.8.0+.

Create a new file in the `nginx` subfolder of your project's `.ddev` directory, e.g. `.ddev/nginx/xmlrpc.conf`. (The file can be named anything as long as it ends in `.conf`.)

Paste in the following:

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on socket
location = '/xmlrpc.php' {
  try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
```

Run `ddev start` to recreate the web container.

This pattern, also used for things like handling `/system/files` paths (for Drupal private files), will prefer a real `xmlrpc.php` file if it exists, and otherwise will ask Drupal's `index.php` (and routing system) to handle the request.